# Missing required argument "[zookeeper]"

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

i'm trying to start a consumer using Apache Kafka, it used to work well, but i had to format my pc and reinstall everything again, and now when trying to run this:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic test --from-beginning
```

this is what i'm getting:

```
Missing required argument "[zookeeper]"
Option                                  Description                            
------                                  -----------                            
--blacklist <blacklist>                 Blacklist of topics to exclude from    
                                          consumption.                         
--bootstrap-server <server to connect                                          
  to>                                                                          
--consumer.config <config file>         Consumer config properties file.       
--csv-reporter-enabled                  If set, the CSV metrics reporter will  
                                          be enabled                           
--delete-consumer-offsets               If specified, the consumer path in     
                                          zookeeper is deleted when starting up
--formatter <class>                     The name of a class to use for         
                                          formatting kafka messages for        
                                          display. (default: kafka.tools.      
                                          DefaultMessageFormatter)             
--from-beginning                        If the consumer does not already have  
                                          an established offset to consume     
                                          from, start with the earliest        
                                          message present in the log rather    
                                          than the latest message.             
--key-deserializer <deserializer for                                           
  key>                                                                         
--max-messages <Integer: num_messages>  The maximum number of messages to      
                                          consume before exiting. If not set,  
                                          consumption is continual.            
--metrics-dir <metrics directory>       If csv-reporter-enable is set, and     
                                          this parameter isset, the csv        
                                          metrics will be outputed here        
--new-consumer                          Use the new consumer implementation.   
--property <prop>                                                              
--skip-message-on-error                 If there is an error when processing a 
                                          message, skip it instead of halt.    
--timeout-ms <Integer: timeout_ms>      If specified, exit if no message is    
                                          available for consumption for the    
                                          specified interval.                  
--topic <topic>                         The topic id to consume on.            
--value-deserializer <deserializer for                                         
  values>                                                                      
--whitelist <whitelist>                 Whitelist of topics to include for     
                                          consumption.                         
--zookeeper <urls>                      REQUIRED: The connection string for    
                                          the zookeeper connection in the form 
                                          host:port. Multiple URLS can be      
                                          given to allow fail-over.
```

my guess is that there's some kind of problem with the zookeeper connection port, because it's telling me to specify the port which zookeeper has to use to get connected to kafka. I'm not sure of this though, and don't know how to figure out the port to specify if this was the problem. Any suggestions??

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Could you please share the version of Kafka you're using?

Comment: Prior to Kafka 0.10, Zookeeper was a required argument

Comment: Hello guys, thank you for your answers. In fact i was using Kafka 0.9 and i didn't notice it, i've installed the latest Kafka version and now it's working just fine. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using an old version of the Kafka tools that requires to set `--new-consumer` if you want to directly connect to the brokers.

I'd recommend picking a recent version of Kafka so you only need to specify `--bootstrap-server` like in your example: http://kafka.apache.org/downloads

Comment: Hello @Mickael Maison, thank you for your answer. You were right, i didn't notice i was running an old Kafka version. The problem got solved as soon as i intalled the latest one. Answer marked as correct, and upvoted!! thank you!! :)